# Рандомный выбор между двумя элементами массива

Tags: c++

У меня есть массив char Cells из 9 элементов. Но теперь мне нужно, чтобы либо Cells[6], либо Cells[8] присвоился 'a'. Как я могу записать это с помощью рандома? В интернете полазил, но там с вычислениями все примеры были. Помогите пожалуйста, а то застрял тут =/

Answer (score 3):

Где то так

```
/* rand example: guess the number */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  int it;
  int ind;
  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand ( time(NULL) );

  /* generate */
  it = rand() % 2;
  if (it == 0) ind = 6; else ind = 8;

   Cells[ind] = 'a';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, а что означает it = rand() % 2; if (it == 0) ??? Можно коротко как то?

Comment: rand() генерит целое число. %2 - получает остаток от деления на 2. Результатом будет либо 0, либо 1 (с вероятностью близкой к 50 на 50).
После этого понятно, почему я сравниваю с нулем.
можно было бы и проще записать `ind = (rand() %2) * 2 + 6;`, но это уже не для учебных целей:)

Comment: Наверное самый простой (или короткий) способ проверки на четность и запись в элемент массива

    Cells[(rand() & 1)? 8: 6] = 'a';

Также, как и в предыдущем примере ind == 6 для четных, а 8 для нечетных. 

Способ базируется на знании машинного представления целых (у четных младший бит - 0, а у нечетных - 1, & - побитовая операция `AND`).

*Как раз в учебных целях*.

Answer (score 1):

Чистый C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main()
{
    char cells[] = "         ";

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cells) / sizeof(cells[0]); i++) {
        int pos = rand() % 10;
        cells[pos] = 'x';
        puts(cells);
        cells[pos] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
 x
x
 x
         x
 x
     x
 x
     x
         x
  x
```

Comment: А первый ответ - "грязный" си ?

Comment: Когда ответ писался, первого еще не было.

Comment: Ваш:

    отвечен 33 минуты назад

Первый:

    отвечен 44 минуты назад

Comment: Т.е. написание примера заняло около 11 минут.

Comment: курил наверно:)